# Sum up date of 2 tables and compare them and return new column based on comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

SOLVED:

Got A Solution, not perfected but can process it further in the frontend to display it! I Basically have 2 selects to create two tables from one and then join them with a inner join where i have in one row all stamp in and stamp outs of the same user within the same day , yay.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate) > 2018  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Stamps',
ISNULL(t.inStampDate, '') as 'inStampDate',
 t.employeeID
FROM dbo.timeRecording t
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate) > 2018
GROUP BY t.employeeID,
     t.inStampDate ) inStamp

INNER JOIN

(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate) > 2018  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Stamps',
ISNULL(t.outStampDate, '') as 'outStampDate',
t.employeeID
FROM dbo.timeRecording t
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate) > 2018
GROUP BY t.employeeID,
     t.outStampDate ) outStamp

ON inStamp.inStampDate = outStamp.outStampDate AND inStamp.employeeID = outStamp.employeeID
```

Previous Situation:

Situation: I have users which can login or stampin and out. These values are being logged. Now I want to show how often a user has stamped in or out in total in a single day.

I have a table in which I have two date values `StampInDate` and `StampOutDate`. Also there is an `employeeID`. I tried to calculate the total amount of stamp in and stamp outs in a single day. I already can show me the total amount of the stamps for each stamp in or stamp out but I cant get that far to compare those values and create a new column "totalStampsThatDay" which will be filled with the count of stamps that day. The error message I get is:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Column 'dbo.timeRecording.employeeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Code that works:

```
SELECT t.employeeID,
DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate) AS 'InYear',                
DATEPART(MONTH, t.inStampDate) AS 'InMonth',              
DATEPART(DAY, t.inStampDate) AS 'InDay',
DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutYear',                  
DATEPART(MONTH, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutMonth',            
DATEPART(DAY, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutDay',
COUNT(t.inStampDate) AS 'StampIns',
COUNT( t.outStampDate) AS 'StampOuts'
FROM dbo.timeRecording t

GROUP BY  DATEPART(DAY, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(MONTH, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(DAY, t.outStampDate),
          DATEPART(MONTH, t.outStampDate),
          DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate),
          t.employeeID
ORDER BY t.employeeID
```

Now my try to edit it to achieve what I want but failed:

```
SELECT tr.StampIns,
tr.StampOuts,
tr.eID,
t.employeeID,
DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate) AS 'InYear',                
DATEPART(MONTH, t.inStampDate) AS 'InMonth',              
DATEPART(DAY, t.inStampDate) AS 'InDay',
DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutYear',                  
DATEPART(MONTH, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutMonth',            
DATEPART(DAY, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutDay'

FROM dbo.timeRecording t
JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(tr.inStampDate) AS 'StampIns',
        COUNT(tr.outStampDate) AS 'StampOuts',
        tr.employeeID as 'eID'
        FROM dbo.timeRecording tr
    ) tr ON tr.eID = t.employeeID

GROUP BY  DATEPART(DAY, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(MONTH, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(DAY, t.outStampDate),
          DATEPART(MONTH, t.outStampDate),
          DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate),
          t.employeeID,
          tr.eID,
          tr.StampIns,
          tr.StampOuts

ORDER BY t.employeeID
```

Something like:

```
employeeID | date    | totalStampsThatDay
1          | 21.11.19| 2
2          | 21.11.19| 0
3          | 22.11.19| 1
1          | 22.11.19| 1
```

... and so on

---- UPDATE ----
Almost got what i wanted. I only need to add a column for the date, e.g. 2019-11-19, but i am unable to do so right now.

```
SELECT t.employeeID,
COUNT(t.inStampDate)  + COUNT( t.outStampDate) as 'TotalStamps',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate) > 2018  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'StampIns',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate) > 2018  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'StampOuts'
FROM dbo.timeRecording t
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate) > 2018 OR DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate) > 2018 
GROUP BY t.employeeID
```

My output so far:

```
 employeeID | Total | In | Out
 7          | 9     | 6  | 3
 8          | 105   | 48 | 57
 11         | 6     | 5  | 1
```

And want:

```
employeeID | Date       | Total | In | Out
7          | 2019-11-19 | 2     | 1  | 1
7          | 2019-11-20 | 3     | 2  | 1
11         | 2019-11-19 | 1     | 1  | 0
11         | 2019-11-16 | 2     | 1  | 1
```

Comment: So, what's the purpose of `GROUP BY ` without any aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.employeeID,
    DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate) AS 'InYear',                
    DATEPART(MONTH, t.inStampDate) AS 'InMonth',              
    DATEPART(DAY, t.inStampDate) AS 'InDay',
    DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutYear',                  
    DATEPART(MONTH, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutMonth',            
    DATEPART(DAY, t.outStampDate) AS 'OutDay',
    COUNT(t.inStampDate)  + COUNT( t.outStampDate) as 'TotalStamps',
FROM dbo.timeRecording t

GROUP BY  DATEPART(DAY, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(MONTH, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(YEAR, t.inStampDate),
          DATEPART(DAY, t.outStampDate),
          DATEPART(MONTH, t.outStampDate),
          DATEPART(YEAR, t.outStampDate),
          t.employeeID
ORDER BY t.employeeID
```

What about this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it works thanks for that. Only one issue. Some times I have a default value, which is 1900-01-01 can i somehow filter those values out? Something like COUNT(IF ( t.inStampDate > 2000-01-01 ? t.inStampDate : 0) ?

Comment: you can add either WHERE or HAVING clause to skip these values.